# Refreshing a widget functionality

Tags: javascript, partial-page-refresh

I have A Vanilla API integrated into my WordPress site.

This API lists the latest discussions but it doesn't refresh the changes in the discussions unless the page is reloaded. All I need is a function that works with the following lines and retrieves the discussions every x second:

```
// Retrieve the latest discussions from the Vanilla API
$resturl = vf_combine_paths($resturl, '/');
$data = json_decode(vf_rest($resturl));
if (!is_object($data))
   return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Javascript timer:

```
// retrieves the discussions every 30 seconds
setInterval ( "refreshDiscussion()", 30000 );

// Retrieve the latest discussions from the Vanilla API
function refreshDiscussion(){
    $resturl = vf_combine_paths($resturl, '/');
    $data = json_decode(vf_rest($resturl));
    if (!is_object($data))
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Although I should mention that the code that I posted was inside another function so maybe it doesn't work because of that? And I don't know how to correct the syntax

Comment: If you could provide the WP site or the entire function I can give you specifics on how to refactor your code.

Comment: Still no response?  Been almost three months.